# Project Run Time does not start on Sagemaker Studio Lab

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

That is the case as of last night. Does not work for CPU or GPU "compute type"
Basically, after pressing the "Start runtime" button, it says "Preparing project runtime..." for about ten minutes and then stops. It shows the following error, "There was a problem when starting the project runtime. This should be resolved shortly. Please try again later."

I have now tried it about five times over last night and this morning.

There is no way to even access the work that is saved there. The "project" will not boot up.

Basically it is a dud at this point.

Is anyone else experiencing similar issues? What does one do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was thinking that there may be other users of Sagemaker Studio Lab on StackOverflow that went through the same issue and found a solution. It was not clear where one would post a request for help when I ran across the issue. Since then, I learned more. So, I'll post that in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The issues/questions and answers that I have learned since (because I was asked to clarify):

(1) The environment on Sagemaker Studio Lab is supposed to be persistent. I.e., any time one starts it, the environment, files uploaded, etc. are where it was left last. However, I was not able to start the environment any longer. Before it locked out, it would start fine. Consequently, I was not able to get to my saved work in any way shape or form. I was wondering if anyone has had this issue

Answer: Thus far not too many people are approved for Sagemaker Studio Lab. So, I may have been the first or one of the first to encounter this issue. As of this writing there does not exist a way to access ones data if one cannot spin up a virtual machine that would have access to the data using their "Start runtime" button.

(2) It is not clear where one is supposed to report issues with Sagemaker Studio Lab. On one's home page in Studio Lab, it has a link to StackOverflow under "Get answers and help others". That is how I ended up here. Though, I should have included the following hashtag (#amazon-sagemaker pointing to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-sagemaker).

Answer: I eventually found where people are submitting bug reports. And I reported the issue there (see issue 56). https://github.com/aws/studio-lab-examples/issues

(3) It was not clear to me if I was to delete my account and request a new one if I would be put on a waitlist (which supposedly is presently long). I.e., this would be the manual factory reboot option where one still loses all of ones work, but, at least has an opportunity to start again with the environment.

Answer: Once one is approved, one does not go to the waitlist. Deleting my account, requesting a new one, and setting it up to the initial state took a couple of minutes for me. And yes, I lost all my work that was on there. So, back stuff up as it was your computer in the `80s. I.e., back up externally to that environment.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I signed up for ASMSL about 2 weeks ago. As of this evening (Feb 15) I'm able to log into my runtime without any trouble at all.